# Viewport width having no effect?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, meta-tags

**Quick Overview of my Problem:**

I made a site for mobile, it looks great. Move on tablet it looks horrible. As in it's like 5x stretched out from left and right. Imagine your face stretched horizontally up to 4ft.

**Research and Possible Solution**

I had a feeling i could viewport. As I thought, if i could just SCALE the layout instead of having browser provide more width and then my layout spreading to accommodate.

Article told me that if i set viewport meta tag **width=300** or anything custom then browser scales whole page to fit the current viewport's actual width so 300px would be covering 1200px, at least that's what my impression was.

However, it **DIDN'T work**. No matter what viewport settings I do they appear to have no effect on scaling.

**What i want**

I want my page to scale up. I don't want to specify every border width in **em** units than create dozen media query checkpoints to increase font size. Especially since my layout remains the same only it needs to scale up.

If i was going after different layouts then obviously i'd've used media queries.

I've tried this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=300">`

Comment: There is such a thing as viewport units. vh and vw are two examples. vh stands for Viewport Height and vw stands for Viewport Width. The value in front is a percentage of the viewport. So 50vw means 50% of the viewport's width. Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln229jmj/

Comment: how would that solve this. I know about them but i couldn't think of a way that would solve this

Comment: It scales with your screen. If you resize the output window in the fiddle, you'll notice the text scales and the box scales.

Comment: oh i see, but that again requires me to do over all values in this format 1.3, 1.34,1.44, 1.932. And i can't be precise like 15px 30px. By precise i mean granularity. 1.3vw and 1.4vw have huge difference in them.

Comment: i got it working check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using some javascript

first add (i'm using jade)

`meta(id="myViewport", name="viewport", content="width=device-width")`

Now `window.innerWidth` will give correct browser width and not some arbitrary number set by browser like 960 which was being reported by chrome on 360 width phone and 2100+ tablet.

Now just check if screen is wide then limit the viewport's width that way browser will scale it up so, for my tablet, 500 pixels will take up 2100 pixels.

```
if (window.innerWidth > 450) {
            var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
            mvp.setAttribute('content','width=500');
} 
        //- first set device width so window.innerwidth shows actual width then change accordingly.
```